# Can't load Google Fonts/icons from a Svelte web component

Tags: javascript, svelte, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a Svelte app (not Kit) compiled as a web component and I'm trying to load Google Fonts and Material Icons, but it only works during development. When I build the component nothing logs.

I've never worked with shadow DOM before. I can't see a `<head>` element, but when I `console.log(document.head)` I can see it with both scripts and a bunch of other svelte scripts.

How do I approach this?

```
  onMount(() => {
    // Include Roboto from Google Fonts
    const link = document.createElement('link')
    link.rel = 'stylesheet'
    link.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap'
    document.head.appendChild(link)

    // Include Material Icons from Google Fonts
    const link2 = document.createElement('link')
    link2.rel = 'stylesheet'
    link2.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20,400,0,-25'
    document.head.appendChild(link2)
  })
```

I can't get other local CSS files to work either.

Comment: Since global styles (execpt inheritable styles) do not style shadowDOM, Font files need to be loaded in the ``document`` (as you do) **AND** inside a style inside shadowDOM